# How do I remove certain words from a string, but only if they appear at the end of the string?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have company names like "The Millard Group" and "The Chimney Corporation". I want to remove the words like "Group" or "Corporation", but only if they appear at the very end of the word. I.e. I don't want to remove them if they appear somewhere in the middle.

How can I go about doing this in Ruby? `gsub` will replace the string from wherever it is, and also I have a list of about ten, so I'd rather not run `gsub` ten times. It would be great if I could provide an array of these words to remove.

Comment: Do you mean end of word or line or string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
['The Millard Group', 'The Chimney Corporation'].each do |s|
  s.gsub!(/\ (Group|Corporation)$/, '')
end
```

You can add more words to remove in the regular expression by adding them after more `|`

Comment: Careful with `$`, it really means "end of line", `\z` and `\Z` mean "end of string" (with different handling of a final newline).

Comment: @Ringo, If this was the best valid answer to your question, would you please give it (or whichever question _was_ the best) the checkmark?  That will show others who find your question which answer helped you.

Answer (score 2):

Because not everything needs to be solved with gsub and regexp:

```
endings = [' Group', ' Corporation']
corporations = ["The Millard Group", "The Chimney Corporation"]

corporations.each do |corp|
  endings.each{|ending| corp.chomp!(ending)}
end

p corporations #=> ["The Millard", "The Chimney"]
```

Edit: Maybe this version could be a little bit faster?

```
corporations.map! do |corp|
  last_word = (corp.rindex(' ')+1)..-1
  corp.slice!(last_word) if endings.include?(corp[last_word])
  corp.rstrip
end
```

Comment: While this is more simple and easier to read, the use of a regex pattern containing the union of the search terms will be faster as the list grows, especially when it's anchored.

Comment: Very nice, @hirolau, very nice indeed.  I seem to always associate `chomp` with `gets.chomp`, forgetting that it can take an argument.  A good reminder.  Maybe insert `rstrip!` after `corp`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following convention:

`\s` for whitespaces/new-lines etc.
`$` denotes at end of line.
`^` denotes at start of line.

Use this now in your regular expression:

```
/\s*(Group|Corporation)$/
```

This will find the *Group* or *Corporation* at end of your given `String` and substitute that with whatever you want.

```
'The Chimney Corporation'.gsub!(/\s*(Group|Corporation)$/,'')
#=>"The Chimney"
```

Comment: Use `\s+` instead of `\s*`. The first forces stripping 1+ white-space characters, which would allow `gsub` to fire only when the word stands by itself. Using `\s*` would allow 0+, even when "Corporation" or "Group" is appended to the previous word which could cause false-positives.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [ "The Millard Group", "The Chimney Corporation", "The Ruby People" ]
BAD_WORDS = %w{ Group Corporation }

arr.reduce([]) do |a,s| 
  s.match( /(.*?)\s+(\w+)\s*$/ )
  a << ( BAD_WORDS.include?($2) ? $1 : s )
end
    # => ["The Millard", "The Chimney", "The Ruby People"]
```

- `arr.reduce([])` creates an empty array, called `a` within the block, into which the possibly modified strings are to be inserted.
- `s.match(/(.*?)\s+(\w+)\s*$/)` has two capture groups; the second one for the last word of the string, `(\w+)`, which is preceded by at least one whitespace character `\s+`, and the first one for everything that precedes that whitespace, `(.*?)`, `?` needed to make it "non-greedy".  The results of the match are stored in `$1` and `$2`.
- we check to see if `$2` (last word of string `s`) is contained in `BAD_WORDS`; if it is we append `$1` to `a`, else we append 
  the entire string `s`.

[Edit: I prefer the other solutions posted to date, but will leave this in the interest of diversity.]